# jQuery slide effect not running online

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have done locally a rating bar with the help of jQuery and I only use .css method and events like click, mouseup, mousedown and mousemove in javascript.

This works like it should locally (offline) but when I am uploading it up on a server it seems to do nothing...

I have tried to see with firebug what is wrong and it seems that online firebug doesn't see the javascript file with the slider but locally it does. Although when I try to view the javascript from the html pagesource(in firefox) it seems to be ok and the javascript fle its there..

Why the slider it doesn't work and why does firebug not seeing the script?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you linking to the correct path, IE, relative or absolute for the remote, not absolute for the local?

Comment: the path is relative eg: js/slider.js .. but I have also other scripts that are called this way and there seem to be ok.. and I can access the script from the page source if I follow the url given by firefox

Comment: can we see code or the page then?

Comment: here is the url http://www.androidstarter.net/test/anime_review.html and the script is js/rating-slider.js, I call it in the head of the html... it should slide the gray little bar when you click on the rating bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, I had wrapped the listeners in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

//my code here
});

And now it works just fine.. I don't know why it worked locally but on the host not but now it works :D

Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: Probably because it was loading almost instantly when local, but needed to wait for the document to be ready when online.